# MapSurfer OSM Missing data at scale

Tags: quickmapservices

I am using QuickMap Services MapSurfer OSM Roads Map, and it seems that there is some data missing. This was previously working for me - I'd use another map and move on, but all the other images in the report are using this as a basemap.

Any ideas?

[image: Missing data]